# How to UPDATE table a column according value from table b in SQLITE?

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables. Table a and table b. They are connected with a.productID = b.productID. My question is How to update TABLE a.column IF TABLE b.culumn contain a specific value. I searched this problem but nothing helped me so I am asking you.

My code (it should be probably something like this):

```
SELECT Cars a
LEFT JOIN Season b ON a.productID = b.productID
SET a.type = "winter" CASE b.month < 3 OR b.month > 11
```

This does not work for me.

Comment: I am using, to show result, sqlite browser. Just for info.

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing what you want to do:

```
update Cars
set Cars.type = 'winter'
where exists (
  select 1 from b where 
  b.productID = Cars.productID and (b.month < 3 OR b.month > 11)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an update with a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Cars a
SET a.type = 'winter'
WHERE
    (SELECT b.month FROM Season b WHERE a.productID = b.productID) < 3 OR
    (SELECT b.month FROM Season b WHERE a.productID = b.productID) > 11;
```